# Forcing home/back/recent apps bar to rotate

Tags: auto-rotation, home-button

I have a Nexus 4, running Android 4.2.1.

There is a bar on the bottom of stock Android with the buttons for navigation. Is there a way to force the bar to rotate with the rest of the screen, like on a tablet?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The bar doesn't rotate, but the buttons do. (The little icons will rotate when the device changes orientation)

Comment: Just a question of preference.

Comment: I see. Is this a rooted device?

Comment: No, but it's not something I mind doing. Just haven't gotten around to it really. It's a new device, 1 week old.

Comment: That's fine. Mine isn't rooted, and to tell you the truth I have no idea how to do this. The Android OS is made to actually remove this area from the screen when displaying content (To help the developers), so moving it might cause some issues.

Comment: @Josiah and `@Dan` [Gravitybox JB](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox) can do the job, provided that device is rooted and Xposed Framework is installed.